# Making AJAX call, getting "Uncaught Reference Error"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

## Problem

I'm trying to make an AJAX call to an API for river data, but I'm having trouble getting the JSON object to appear in my console. Instead, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery21309662145180627704_1432235037636 is not defined`

**Update #1 - Added in missing AJAX call code**

### AJAX Call

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://opengov.brandon.ca/OpenDataService/default.aspx?format=jsonp&dataset=riverlevel&columns=Date',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

**API documentation:** http://opengov.brandon.ca/api.aspx

**Query String:**

```
?format=jsonp&dataset=riverlevel&columns=Date
```

Going to the [url for the AJAX call](http://opengov.brandon.ca/OpenDataService/default.aspx?format=jsonp&dataset=riverlevel&columns=Date), I see this:

```
jsonpcallback([
  {
    "Date" : "19/05/2015 12:26:05 PM",
    "River Level (ft)" : "1170.16000",
    "River Level (m)" : "356.66477"
  },
  {
    "Date" : "15/05/2015 9:01:20 AM",
    "River Level (ft)" : "1170.51000",
    "River Level (m)" : "356.77145"
  },
  {
    "Date" : "14/05/2015 9:08:09 AM",
    "River Level (ft)" : "1170.84000",
    "River Level (m)" : "356.87203"
  },
```

Comment: It sounds like you're making a JSONP request to a location which doesn't return JSONP

Comment: Can you post your code making the AJAX call?

Comment: Can you provide the JavaScript code that is making the Ajax call?

Comment: Shouldn't this be requested via a script tag instead of an AJAX call? If you want JSON, you should be requesting [this url instead](http://opengov.brandon.ca/OpenDataService/default.aspx?format=json&dataset=riverlevel&columns=Date) (note json instead of jsonp as the format param.

Comment: well you are making a jsonp call and not a JSON call. Show your code.

Comment: Also, where is the query variable? In the documentation it says "The default data format is XML, but can be changed by setting the format query variable to "json" to return JSON formatted data."..

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck it's in the query string.

Comment: Okay now I see that after clicking on the URL.. Should be posted in the question IMO.

Comment: What is the actual code for the Ajax call you are making?

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck In talking with the developer who made/works with the API at the city, he said it can be outputted in JSONP. I just added my AJAX call code, totally thought it was in there before.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Added in the AJAX call code.

Comment: Add `jsonpCallback: 'jsonpcallback'` to your ajax function options.

Comment: Avoid hardcoded names. They tend to lead to race conditions.

Comment: Just to clarify: does your code reaches the "success" function? Or does it fail before anything? If you add an "error" function, does it call it? If so, are you calling the Ajax function from a button inside a "FORM" tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API you are calling isn't implementing JSONP properly.

The callback name is case sensitive, but the API is converting it to all lower case in the response. This is a problem because the name that jQuery will generate for you starts with `jQuery` (with a capital Q).

In order to hack around this, you need to generate your own callback name (instead of letting jQuery do it for you) and ensure that it doesn't include any capital letters.

```js
function callbackName() {
  return "jquery_callback" + Date.now();
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://opengov.brandon.ca/OpenDataService/default.aspx?format=jsonp&dataset=riverlevel&columns=Date&callback=?',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
  jsonpCallback: callbackName
});
```